# How to pass an argument via reference into an async closure?

Tags: rust

I am working on a tokio subsystem management tool, and as part of that I need to spawn a subsystem via `tokio::spawn`. The crux here is that I need to pass some parameters into the subsystem - **via reference**. (The reference thing here is the important part; I already have a solution if I skip the reference requirement, but I wanted to see if it's possible)

So I have the following:

- A function `run_subsys` that takes an `async FnOnce(&MyArgs) -> i32` (pseudocode, of course). The function generates the `MyArgs` object and executes it via `tokio::spawn`.
- A `main` function that calls the `run_subsys` function with an `|args| async {}`.

The problem that I'm on now is how to deal with lifetimes. The `args` in `|args| async {}` obviously is a reference and gets returned from the closure as a future, with its lifetime still attached.

So how do I annotate this in the `where` clause of `run_subsys`? Is this even possible in current Rust?

This is mybest effort so far (MRE-ified, obviously):

```rust
use std::future::Future;

use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyArgs(i32);

// Goal: have a function that accepts an async closure.
// The closure should take a custom struct (here MyArgs),
// **as a reference**. The reference part is the crux here,
// otherwise this would be easy.
async fn run_subsys<'a, Fut, Subsys>(subsys: Subsys)
where
    Subsys: 'static + FnOnce(&'a MyArgs) -> Fut + Send,
    Fut: 'a + Future<Output = i32> + Send,
{
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        // Spawn the subsystem with custom args.
        // The important part is that I can only
        // pass the args via reference.
        let s = MyArgs(42);
        let result = subsys(&s).await;
        println!("Arguments were: {:?}, Result: {}", s, result);
    })
    .await
    .unwrap();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    run_subsys(|x| async {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        println!("Arguments: {:?}", x);
        69
    })
    .await;
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:22:29
   |
12 | async fn run_subsys<'a, Fut, Subsys>(subsys: Subsys)
   |                     -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
21 |         let s = MyArgs(42);
   |             - binding `s` declared here
22 |         let result = subsys(&s).await;
   |                      -------^^-
   |                      |      |
   |                      |      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                      argument requires that `s` is borrowed for `'a`
23 |         println!("Arguments were: {:?}, Result: {}", s, result);
24 |     })
   |     - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a hard problem. The easiest solution is to box the retuned future, if boxing is acceptable.

Comment: Sadly, no. Well, that's also an answer :) I'm fine with that. Maybe that changes at some point in the future.

Comment: In the duplicate I showed a way to do that if the closure is not capturing (basically, if you can convert it to `async fn`). I believe there is also a way to do that with capturing closures if you're willing to rely on nightly. There's no perfect in life :)